# Ninject EventBroker automatic registration

Tags: events, ninject

Is it possible to get all injected items to automatically be registered with the EventBroker? The alternate is to inject the IEventBroker in each type, but this is error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot register them when an object is injected. But you can register an object when it is created by using `.RegisterOnGlobalEventBroker();` or/and `RegisterOnEventBroker("MyGlobalEventBroker")` from https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker